# IndexError: range object index out of range error

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Hi I have following code which runs out of index. How can I fix the indexing for a matrix which can solve out of range error.

I have tried modifying the Filter range. But it is of no luck.

```
Filters = range(0,32)   
for j in MapSizes:
    if MapSizes[j] == 32:
         LayerMapInference[j] = repmat(np.array(MapInference, 8,8, len(Filters[j][3]),Batchsize))
    elif MapSizes[j] == 16:
         LayerMapInference[j] = repmat(np.array(MapInference, 4,4, len(Filters[j][3]),Batchsize))
    elif MapSizes[j] == 8:
         LayerMapInference[j] = repmat(np.array(MapInference, 2,2, len(Filters[j][3]),Batchsize))
```

Equivalent Matlab code:

```
if MapSizes(j) == 32
        LayerMapInference{j} = repmat(MapInference,8,8,size(Filters{j},3),BatchSize);
    elseif MapSizes(j) == 16
        LayerMapInference{j} = repmat(MapInference,4,4,size(Filters{j},3),BatchSize);
    elseif MapSizes(j) == 8
        LayerMapInference{j} = repmat(MapInference,2,2,size(Filters{j},3),BatchSize);
    end
```

Please let me know how can I fix this error.

Solution with np.tile resulting the same error

```
for j in MapSizes:

        if MapSizes[j] == 32:
                 LayerMapInference[j] = np.tile(MapInference, 8,8, Filters[j].shape[2],Batchsize)
        elif MapSizes[j] == 16:
                 LayerMapInference[j] = np.tile(MapInference, 4,4, Filters[j].shape[2],Batchsize)
        elif MapSizes[j] == 8:
                 LayerMapInference[j] = np.tile(MapInference, 2,2, Filters[j].shape[2],Batchsize)
```

Comment: `Filters[j][3]` won’t work because it is a 1d list. You need `Filters[j]` without `[3]`

Comment: @Sheldore Yes, you can index range objects.

Comment: @Selcuk : In that case the error is clear, it comes from the double indexing of a 1d list

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do?

Comment: How can I define Filter range for a matrix?

Comment: What is the exact error message, including the traceback?

Comment: What are you expecting `len(Filters[j][3])` to return? `Filters[j]` is just the number `j`.

Comment: What is `MapSizes`?  What is `np.array(MapInference, 8,8, len(Filters[j][3])` supposed to be doing?  The second argument to `np.array` is supposed to a `dtype`, not a number like `8`.  What's `repmat`?

Comment: `range(0,32)[32]` produces your error message.  The rest of `len(Filters[j][3])` is a mystery.  Are you trying to adapt MATLAB code?

Comment: Yes I am trying to convert a matlab code to Python here.

Comment: Just to make more sense I am adding Matlab code as well.

Comment: repmat is equivalent of np.tile(). I saw it can be leveraged as is from matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(0,32)` in Python is like `0:31` in MATLAB, except it's not evaluated until used (as in a `for` loop, or `list(range(0,32))`).

If recall MATLAB correctly, `LayerMapInference{j}` must be a `cell`, with the `{}` indexing (as opposed to () matrix indexing).

I read `size(Filters{j},3)` as:

```
 Filters{j}     # the jth item in the Filters cell
 size(...,3)    # the 3rd dimension of that object (a 3d matrix?)
```

In `numpy` that would be roughly

```
 Filters[j].shape[2]
```

where `Filters` is a list or object dtype array that can hold a diverse collection of items.  The `[j]` item (counting from 0) must be an array, with a `shape` attribute.  `np.size(Filters[j],2)` would also work, but usually we use `shape` rather than `size` (with the axis parameter).

So

```
repmat(MapInference,8,8,size(Filters{j},3),BatchSize)
```

takes a `MapInference` matrix, and replicates it to make a `(8,8,size(),BatchSize)` shaped matrix (4d).

`numpy.matlab.repmat` is like an old time MATLAB `repmat` (v 3.5). It's meant to work with `np.matrix` which is a 2d array.

```
In [659]: repmat(np.arange(4),3,2)                                                                     
Out[659]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
In [660]: repmat(np.arange(4),3,2,3)                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-660-c5acb9021d92> in <module>
----> 1 repmat(np.arange(4),3,2,3)

TypeError: repmat() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

So use `np.repeat` or `np.tile` instead.

Comment: I understood the difference between matlab repmat function and python tile quite clearly form your explanation. Way to read size(Filters{j},3) is been explained clearly. But unfortunately even after implementing the code as per your explanation is still giving me the same error. I have edited my solution accordingly.